# Limit involving integral $\frac{1}{r}\int_0^r f(s)\, ds \to0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

$$ \lim_{r\to 0}\left(  r\int_0^r \frac{s^{n-1}}{s^2\log s}\, ds\right) $$

### I am considering $ r $ small, r <1/2 and $n$ an integer.

For me, intuitively, I notice that the integral converges to zero. I tried to make a substitution, like $ t = | \log s | $, but I was not well sustained.

Comment: Is it $r$ or $1/r$ before the integral ?

Comment: Why don't you just write the integrand as $\frac{s^{n-3}}{\log s}$?

Comment: What if $n=1?$ You need to tell us what $n$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p>-1$, and $0 < r < \tfrac12$, then
$$ \int_0^r s^p (\log(1/s))^\alpha \, ds \approx r^{p+1} (\log(1/r))^\alpha ,$$
where $A \approx B$ means there exists a constant $C>0$ with $C^{-1} A \le B \le C A$.  The constant gets worse as $p \to 1+$.

Proof: See that for $\epsilon>0$, there exists $C>0$ such that for all $0<t<1$ and $0 < r< \frac12$ that
$$  1 \le \frac{\log(1/(rt))}{\log(1/r)} = 1 + \frac{\log(1/t)}{\log(1/r)} \le 1 + \frac{\log(1/t)}{\log(2)} \le C t^\epsilon .$$

So if you write $f(r) = r^p (\log(1/r))^\alpha$, then you realize that there exists constants $C_1, C_2>0$ and $-1 < p_1 < p < p_2 < \infty$ such that for $0<t<1$ we have
$$ C_1 t^{p_2} f(r) \le f(r t) \le C_2 t^{p_1} f(r) . $$
Also
$$ \int_0^r f(s) \, ds = r \int_0^1 f(rt) \, d t $$
and so
$$ \frac{C_1}{1-p_2} r f(r) \le \int_0^r f(s) \, ds \le \frac{C_2}{1-p_1} r f(r) , $$
or
$$ \int_0^r f(s) \, ds \approx r f(r) . $$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would know what values $\alpha$ can assume and how you get the inequities involving f(rt), the first one you mentioned, before “Also”.

Comment: This works for any $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.  For the inequalities, use $C_3 \le \log(1/r) \le C_4 r^\epsilon$ for $0 < r \le \tfrac12$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** if $f$ is differentiable,
$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(r)-f(0)}{r-0} = f'(0)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
As an example, I'll assume $\ds{\large\color{red}{n > 2}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{r \to 0}\bracks{r\int_{0}^{r}{s^{n - 1} \over s^{2}\ln\pars{s}}\,\dd s}}\,\,\,\stackrel{s\ =\ \expo{-t}}{=}\,\,\,
\lim_{r \to 0}\bracks{r\int_{\infty}^{-\ln\pars{r}}{\expo{-\pars{n - 2}t} \over t}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] = &
-\lim_{r \to 0}\bracks{r\int_{-\pars{n - 2}\ln\pars{r}}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over t}\,\dd t}
=
-\lim_{r \to 0}\bracks{r\,\mrm{E}_{1}\pars{-\pars{n - 2}\ln\pars{r}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\lim_{r \to 0}\bracks{r\,
{\expo{\pars{n - 2}\ln\pars{r}} \over -\pars{n - 2}\ln\pars{r}}} =
{1 \over n - 2}\lim_{r \to 0}{r^{n - 1} \over \ln\pars{r}}
= \bbx{\large 0} \\ &
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\mrm{E}_{1}}$ is the
[Exponential Integral Function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E1). In evaluating the limit I used the
[$\ds{\mrm{E}_{1}}$ asymptotic Expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.E1).

Comment: Thanks @Felix-Marin for the help. how did you get the result of the limit $\lim_{r\to0} E_1(-(n-2)\ln r)$?

Comment: @Aldo I add some comment at my answer very end. You're welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{r \to 0} r\int_0^r \frac{s^{n-1}}{s^2 \log s} \text{d}s=\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\int_0^r \frac{s^{n-1}}{s^2 \log s}\text{d}s}{\frac{1}{r}}$$
By De L'Hôpital rule
$$\lim_{r \to 0}  \frac{\int_0^r \frac{s^{n-1}}{s^2 \log s}\text{d}s}{\frac{1}{r}} =\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^2 \log r}}{-\frac{1}{r^2}}=\lim_{r\to 0} -\frac{r^{n-1}}{\log r}=0$$
For all $n \geq 1$.